# Matrix of similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $0<k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $F$ be a field, and $p \in F[x]$ be monic and irreducible.
Let $C(p^k)$ be the companion matrix of $p^k$.
Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}
C(p^k) & A \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}$ with minimal polynomial $p^k$. Then $X$ is similar to $C(p^k) \oplus D$ for some matrix $D$.

Question: Can the matrix of similarity be taken to be block upper triangular conformal to $X$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user1551 Hello, yes. Sorry I forgot to say it. I have edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: The statement before you question is false, we cannot conclude that $X$ is similar to $C(p)\oplus D$ for any matrix $D$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Good day, Sir. I have edited my post. If the minimal polynomial of $X$ is $p^k$, then the characteristic polynomial of $X$ is $p^n$ for some $0<n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, $C(p^k)$ must be in the Frobenius canonical form of $X$. This is why I said $X$ is similar to $C(p^k) \oplus D$ for some matrix $D$. Could you please point out if I miss something?

Comment: I had missed that $X$ has the same characteristic polynomial, my mistake

Comment: I think your statement is correct. In the language of Hoffman and Kunze, it would be sufficient to show that the column space of $[C(p^k),0]$ (the first “block-column”) forms an “$X$-admissible subspace”, which means that there exists a complementary invariant subspace.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for your comments, Sir. About my question, I am not sure if it is true or not. (I hope it's true tho.) Could you please recommend a method or readings I can look into to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. This is a special case of a slightly more general fact: let $f$ be any monic non-constant polynomial and $X=\pmatrix{C(f)&A\\ 0&B}$. If $f(X)=0$, then the equation $CY-YB=A$ is solvable and hence
$$
\pmatrix{I&Y\\ 0&I}\pmatrix{C&A\\ 0&B}\pmatrix{I&-Y\\ 0&I}
=\pmatrix{C&0\\ 0&B}.
$$
For a proof that $CY-YB=A$ is solvable, see Robert Hartwig, [*Roth’s removal rule revisited*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(83)90096-4), LAA 49:91-115(1983), section 4, theorem 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a godsend.